# Questions with ignored tags still visible in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, ignored-tags

I have set to ignore [php] tag and chose to hide questions in preferences:

> [image: hide]

But I still see questions tagged [php] in the iOS app.

> [image: app]

Seems the app can't distinguish options for ignored tags.

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Maybe some local cache? Did you try force-closing the app and starting it again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just did it, nothing changed. Does it work for you?

Comment: No iOS app, was just guessing. So probably a bug indeed, we need Brian. Too bad he's now working full time on the Stack Overflow app, so no more bug fixes in the old app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is SE app now deprecated?

Comment: Officially? Of course not. But since all the dev team (aka Brian) is working on something else, and that something else is huge project that will last for years, I can say for almost sure: bugs in the SE app won't be fixed any  more, and no features will be added. It was good while it lasted, but they took Brian away from "us". :/

Comment: @Sha last update to the iOS app (beta anyway) was less than two weeks ago. Sure Brian's not just working on both? (actually, last public update was 4 days ago)

Comment: @Cai being Brian, maybe he has the super ability to work on both somehow. But I'm afraid it can't last forever, and when shipped, there will be zillions of bugs to fix in the new app, urgently, so they won't let him spend time on the old app.

Comment: @Sha sure, looks like there's still reasonably steady updates at the moment though so try to get as many things fixed now while we can, I say :)

Comment: While bug fixes have slowed, they haven't completely stopped.  (They'll always slow while working on new features.)  The good news is that there is *significant* overlap between the two apps.  About 65% of the source files originally in SE are in both apps now and SO only has 21 unique source files.

Comment: @BrianNickel where I can read more about new app?

Comment: There's not much out about it right now, just https://stackapps.com/q/7176/25485, but there will be a blog post when it ships, which will be pretty soon.  It's not terribly exciting if you already use the SE app, especially if you use any other site, but it'll hopefully be better a better experience for Stack Overflow users.