# Filter out tags

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Create a filter, so that questions with a specific tag are not shown.

For example, in the sci-if group, I couldn’t care less about Harry Potter and it would be easier to browse if I could filter the many Harry Potter questions out.

Comment: It's possible on the desktop site to set a tag as "ignored", so that it won't show on the homepage. However, this isn't yet functioning in the iOS app: [Questions with ignored tags still visible in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295786/questions-with-ignored-tags-still-visible-in-ios-app)